# Importing a typescript module to a JS module in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React app created with create-react-app. Recently I've added some source code for a module I need. It's in Typescript and will stay in Typescript. Not my choice.
I've installed what I needed to build Typescript and that part seems to work OK.

However, when I try importing that TS module to my regular jsx, it says `module not found`.

To illustrate:

```
shared/
    - MyTSModule/
        - index.tsx
    - OtherModule/
        - index.jsx
view/
    - MyView/
        - index.jsx
```

I'm trying to import `MyTSModule` to `MyView`. The error is: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'shared/MyTSModule' in...`

I'm importing like all the other modules from `shared`:

```
import MyTSModule from 'shared/MyTSModule ';
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you only processing through typescript with js enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot import typescript file from javascript. You either need to:

1. compile typescript to javascript and then import compiled file
2. convert your javascript files to typescript.

I personally recommend porting all files to typescript, this way you will have more type safety.

Comment: I thought compiling TS to JS would happen on the fly and that compiled JS would automatically be imported.